# How to assert a div in a React component's data attributes using Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, enzyme

I have a React component that creates a `<div>` with custom data-attributes eg

```js
<div className="video-wrapper" data-video-source="brightcove" />
```

Using Enzyme I can assert the classes like so

```js
it('creates a div with correct oVideo attributes', () => {
    const videoDiv = component.find('div.video-wrapper')
    expect(videoDiv.hasClass('video-wrapper')).to.equal(true);
});
```

But how can I assert that the `data-video-source` attribute has the value `brightcove`?

Comment: are you using chai-enzyme?

Comment: @QoP I'm not, I did see that just after I posted this but it still doesn't really look ideal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `.prop()` method:

```
it('creates a div with correct oVideo attributes', () => {
    const videoDiv = component.find('div.video-wrapper')
    expect(videoDiv.hasClass('video-wrapper')).to.equal(true);
    expect(videoDiv.prop('data-video-source')).to.equal('brightcove');
});
```

Comment: Urg! Yes thank you. I had tried to use `.prop()` before for asserting `this.props` to little success. It seems as though it's not named extremely descriptively (or maybe that's just me). Thanks!